# Place and insert plane image along path using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, image, matplotlib

My code is a fair bit more advanced, but in simple terms I am looking to place and rotate an image of a plane along a path using matplotlib. Ideally I would be able to select the angle and how far along the path the image should be placed. Any ideas? My ideal output would be something like this (ignoring the coordinates I already fixed that in my real code).

**[image: strong text]**

Image of Norway used:

[image]

## Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

def x2map(x, x_scale):
    return x * x_scale

def y2map(y, y_scale):
    return (1 - y) * y_scale


if __name__ == "__main__":

    image_url = "Norge2.png"

    # Obtains the scaling for the figure
    map = img.imread(image_url)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    im = ax.imshow(map)
    _, x_scale = plt.xlim()
    y_scale, _ = plt.ylim()

    # Fixes the axis to 0-1 and 0-1
    positions_x = [i * x_scale / 10 for i in range(0, 11)]
    positions_y = [i * y_scale / 10 for i in range(0, 11)]
    labels = [i / 10 for i in range(0, 11)]
    ax.set_xticks(positions_x)
    ax.set_xticklabels([i / 10 for i in range(0, 11)])
    ax.set_yticks(positions_y)
    ax.set_yticklabels([(10 - i) / 10 for i in range(0, 11)])

    route_color = "red"
    route_ls = "-"
    city_marker ="o"
    city_color = "red"

    A = [x2map(0.125,x_scale), y2map(0.14,y_scale)]
    B = [x2map(0.772,x_scale), y2map(0.92,y_scale)]

    plt.plot(
        [A[0], B[0]], [A[1], B[1]], marker='o', color=route_color, ls=route_ls
    )
    plt.show()
```

Comment: is this for an animation? You can place in image on the chart with fig.figimage().

Comment: @mullinscr Yes, the goal is eventually to do an animation. however, I think I can manage that once I figure out how to insert _and_ rotate an image =)